# Header and Sub Header in DataFrame possible?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary (which consists of about 15 different leagues(Columns) that are always changing):

```
{'NFL': [{'Name': 'Taysom Hill', 'Line': '0.5', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'},
  {'Name': 'Derek Carr', 'Line': '238.5', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'},
  {'Name': 'Jared Goff', 'Line': '251.5', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'}],
 'MLB': [{'Name': 'Brandon Pfaadt', 'Line': '4.0','Prop': 'Pitcher Strikeouts'},
  {'Name': 'Ranger Suárez', 'Line': '3.0', 'Prop': 'Pitcher Strikeouts'},
  {'Name': 'Trea Turner', 'Line': '1.5', 'Prop': 'Total Bases'},
```

Which I am attempting to put into a dataframe with a Header and Sub-Headers

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Results, orient="index").stack().to_frame()
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Result:

```
        Name    Line    Prop
NFL 0   Taysom Hill 0.5 Pass Yards
        1   Derek Carr  238.5   Pass Yards
        2   Jared Goff  251.5   Pass Yards
        3   Lamar Jackson   219.5   Pass Yards
        4   Gardner Minshew 218.5   Pass Yards
... ... ... ... ...
Dota2   11  kiyotaka    15.5    MAPS 1-2 Kills
        12  Lou 14.0    MAPS 1-2 Kills
        13  Somnus  19.0    MAPS 1-2 Kills
        14  K1  9.5 MAPS 1-2 Kills
        15  Gunnar  11.5    MAPS 1-2 Kills
```

I have also attempted to transpose `df2 = df.transpose()` the DF which gives me this result:

[image: transposed_df]

```
    NFL ... Dota2
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 6   
Name    Taysom Hill Derek Carr  Jared Goff  Lamar Jackson   Gardner Minshew Josh Allen  Desmond Ridder  Baker Mayfield  Kenny Pickett   Joshua Dobbs    ... 23savage    Mikoto  shiro   NothingToSay    RAMZES666   kiyotaka    Lou Somnus  K1  Gunnar
Line    0.5 238.5   251.5   219.5   218.5   255.5   212.5   229.5   219.5   219.5   ... 9.5 12.5    17.0    15.5    10.5    15.5    14.0    19.0    9.5 11.5
Prop    Pass Yards  Pass Yards  Pass Yards  Pass Yards  Pass Yards  Pass Yards  Pass Yards  Pass Yards  Pass Yards  Pass Yards  ... MAPS 1-2 Kills  MAPS 1-2 Kills  MAPS 1-2 Kills  MAPS 1-2 Kills  MAPS 1-2 Kills
```

What I would like the DF to look like is:

```
              **NFL**                                  **NBA** 
    Name       Line       Prop           Name           Line       Prop
1 Taysom Hill   0.5     Pass Yards      Michael Jordan    39      Points Scored
2 PLAYER 2      25.5    Pass Yards      Player X          45      Points Scored 
3 Player C      19      Pass Yards      Player 3          23      Points Scored
```

I am VERY new to Python... Is this even possible to do? Any help is greatly appreciated!

*****EDIT*****

It seems I'm very close to my goal using the code below, It's just only currently displaying 1 row of results for some reason though when there should be many more.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Results, orient="index")
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist(), index=df.index)
df2 = df.transpose()
```

[df2_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjVcb.png)

Comment: You can use `MultiIndex` in pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: @kelvt - That works, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension to create a list of `dataframes` and concatenate them in order to get a header and subheader. Here is how you can do it using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'NFL': [
        {'Name': 'Taysom Hill', 'Line': '0.5', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'},
        {'Name': 'PLAYER 2', 'Line': '25.5', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'},
        {'Name': 'Player C', 'Line': '19', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'}
    ],
    'NBA': [
        {'Name': 'Michael Jordan', 'Line': '39', 'Prop': 'Points Scored'},
        {'Name': 'Player X', 'Line': '45', 'Prop': 'Points Scored'},
        {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Line': '23', 'Prop': 'Points Scored'}
    ]
}

# Using list comprehension to create a list of dataframes and concatenate them
df_combined = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(data[key]) for key in data], 
    axis=1, 
    keys=data.keys()
)

print(df_combined)
```

which results in

```
           NFL                               NBA                    
          Name  Line        Prop            Name Line           Prop
0  Taysom Hill   0.5  Pass Yards  Michael Jordan   39  Points Scored
1     PLAYER 2  25.5  Pass Yards        Player X   45  Points Scored
2     Player C    19  Pass Yards        Player 3   23  Points Scored
```

OR

As kelvt commented, you can use Pandas `multiindex` to achieve the same.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'NFL': [
        {'Name': 'Taysom Hill', 'Line': '0.5', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'},
        {'Name': 'PLAYER 2', 'Line': '25.5', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'},
        {'Name': 'Player C', 'Line': '19', 'Prop': 'Pass Yards'}
    ],
    'NBA': [
        {'Name': 'Michael Jordan', 'Line': '39', 'Prop': 'Points Scored'},
        {'Name': 'Player X', 'Line': '45', 'Prop': 'Points Scored'},
        {'Name': 'Player 3', 'Line': '23', 'Prop': 'Points Scored'}
    ]
}

# Convert nested dictionaries to dataframes
dfs = {key: pd.DataFrame(value) for key, value in data.items()}

# Construct multi-level columns
new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data.keys(), ['Name', 'Line', 'Prop']])

# Combine dataframes horizontally
df_combined = pd.concat(dfs.values(), axis=1)
df_combined.columns = new_cols

print(df_combined)
```

which results in

```
           NFL                               NBA                    
          Name  Line        Prop            Name Line           Prop
0  Taysom Hill   0.5  Pass Yards  Michael Jordan   39  Points Scored
1     PLAYER 2  25.5  Pass Yards        Player X   45  Points Scored
2     Player C    19  Pass Yards        Player 3   23  Points Scored
```

Comment: I did end up using the MultiIndex as I didn't feel like messing around with what I was attempting anymore. Thank you!